# auto backup the data of a web project in windows 10 MYSQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups, mysql-5.7, database-security

i have created an inventory system (web-based) for a store which runs only in a system hosted by the same system
i want to set a scheduled backup like if the person is entering data in the system so mysql automatically create a backup copy of data in a usb and this should happen daily or on every entry, how it may be possible
kindly help

Comment: Backing a database up is not a programming related question, but a database admin one. The DBA sister site of SO deal with such questions, while SO focuses on programming related ones.

Comment: Do you want to copy **the whole database** on each particular database change? really? This is absolutely illogical. Please be more detailed.

Comment: the issue is that this website is not on internet or any network it is a single system website so to assure data security i want a solution to backup the data that has been entered if anyone have better option please guide i am new to databases

Answer (score 0):

i got to a solution with this
`mysqldump -u root -p databasename>backupfilename.sql`

just go to the directory where you want to save the backup file and run the previous command with your db name and the file name you want to create

create a .bat file of this command and put that .bat file in your windows task scheduler and set a time for that task
the auto backup will be working after that